# Can Titanium Studio coexist with an existing Eclipse install?

Tags: eclipse, titanium

I'm interested in trying out Titanium for mobile development, and it looks like the best way to do that is to use their customized Eclipse-based IDE.  But, I currently use Eclipse for most of my web and android development, and I don't want to risk hosing that installation by installing the Titanium IDE.

So my question is... can Titanium Studio and a standard Eclipse installtion co-exist on the same machine without any conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can install both Titanium Studio and Eclipse in same machine. This will not affect your eclipse and it won't make any conflicts. I have installed both together in my system and it works great.